# dlib dnn_face_recognition_ex trained model not detecting person with training images

Tags: opencv, dlib

i trained resnet model using dlib_metric_learning_on_images.
but when i'm using it for tests and try to detect any of image in johns directory it is unable to detect any person. however when i use trained model on bald_guys.jpg it detects them all as one person.
what am i doing wrong while training?

i also changed input_rgb_image_sized class of face_recognition to input_rgb_image class.

note:- model is trained on johns faces folder and testing it on same image bald_guys.jpg in faces folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These example programs are documentation that explain how to use the library.  That "jonhs" dataset is a tiny set of 61 faces.  It is there to make the example programs runnable.  61 faces is not remotely enough to make a good face recognition model.  Good models, like the one that comes with dlib, are trained on millions of faces.

Comment: 1)so suppose i select 10 individuals and around 1000 images of each. do you think that would be sufficient for detection of only those 10 precisely?
2) the one that you had trained on git repository could you explain the dataset amount for that? for detecting individuals from bald_guys.jpg

Comment: The public dlib model is trained on 3 million faces.  Using just 10 people for training is probably not good either.  You should instead use the public dlib model and train a linear SVM on it or use k-NN classification.

Comment: Which program do you suggest i should use for training to extend public dlib model?

Comment: which program do you suggest i should use for training to extend public dlib model